# First Record in Object Always Null in push()

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I have an interesting issue.

In the component, I have an iteration over records in an object:

```
<aura:iteration items="{!v.cropPlanCrops}" var="cropPlanCrop">
                <lightning:select name="Crop"
                                  aura:id="Crop"
                                  value="{!cropPlanCrop.Crop__c}"
                                  label="Crop" >
                    <aura:iteration items="{!v.crops}" var="crop" >
                        <option value="{!crop.Id}" text="{!crop.Name}" />
                    </aura:iteration>
                </lightning:select>
```

On button click (not in code above, obviously), this method is called in the controller:

```
newCropPlanCrop : function (component, event, helper) {
    let rowItemList = component.get("v.cropPlanCrops");
    rowItemList.push( { 'sobjectType': 'Estimated_Crop_Plan_Crop__c',
                        'Crop__c': null,
                        'Acres__c': null,
                        'Producer_Estimated_Yield__c': null,
                        'Producer_Expected_Price__c': null});
```

For some reason, the first record created (chronologically) in the Crop__c object is always set to null. For example, Barley was the first record I created in the sandbox. It would always return null. I deleted Barley, and now Canola is always returns null. I know this because I created another Barley record and that record returns with the ID and name, therefore, it isn't based on alphabetical order.

I have logged a helper method that accurately returns all IDs and names of crops, so I know that Canola (and the old Barley) were returning the correct data.

Here is an example of the log for the array that is being pushed. Canola is the second element in the array. Not that it is set to null, but other crops are set the appropriate id:

[image]

Comment: You may like to post some more relevant code as if you are fetching values from apex controllers, apart from this JS function, if there's any other JS function which manipulates any data, etc. These information will help to kind of replicate the issue and will be helpful for anyone to assist.

Comment: @JayantDas is correct - you are iterating over the `cropPlanCrops` attribute and we cannot see how you populate your data into it

Comment: Sorry I couldn't reply yesterday! What is most helpful to see? The Apex Controller? UI? I don't want to over post.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue last week, but haven't had a chance to update until now.

The problem is that the first value in `lightning:select` is always returned as `null`. So, when the first element in the object over which I was iterating to populate the `lightning:select` always returned null. It was not an active selection.

To solve this issue, I simply created another option in the `lightning:select` with an empty string value and the title "Please select a crop." Now, selecting a crop from the drop down works perfectly.

```
<lightning:select name="Crop"
                  aura:id="Crop"
                  value="{!cropPlanCrop.Crop__c}"
                  label="Crop" >

       <!--This option adds a placeholder-->
       <option value = "" 
               text="Please select a crop">
       </option>

       <!-- Iterating over the records in the Crop__c object. Defined as an       
       attribute in the controller-->

       <aura:iteration items="{!v.crops}" var="crop" >
             <option value="{!crop.Id}" text="{!crop.Name}" />
        </aura:iteration>
 </lightning:select>
```